# How To Set the index start value to 1 from 0 in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
class AnatomyChapters extends StatefulWidget {
      const AnatomyChapters({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _AnatomyChaptersState createState() => _AnatomyChaptersState();
    }

    class _AnatomyChaptersState extends State<AnatomyChapters> {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
         child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: List<Widget>.generate(
              6,
              (index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('Chapter $index'),
                onTap: () {
                  if (index == 1) {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnaChap1()));
                  } else if (index == 2) {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnaChap2()));
                   }
                 },
                ),
               ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

When Generating a List of widgets(`ListTile`), The first index name shows 0, I want it to display index starting from 1.

[image]

Comment: You could change `title: Text('Chapter $index')` to `title: Text('Chapter ${index + 1}')`

Answer (score 0):

Iteration in flutter started from 0 to (n-1). If you wants to display index from 1 to n than you can increase index by one. Have a look on below code.

```
 class AnatomyChapters extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnatomyChapters({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnatomyChaptersState createState() => _AnatomyChaptersState();
}

class _AnatomyChaptersState extends State<AnatomyChapters> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
    height: double.infinity,
     child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
          6,
          (index) => ListTile(
            title: Text('Chapter ${index+1}'),
            onTap: () {
              if (index == 1) {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnaChap1()));
              } else if (index == 2) {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnaChap2()));
               }
             },
            ),
           ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Except you're off-by-one now.  Should be if "index == 0" go to AnaChap1(). :)